# Unable to Update Mysql Database using Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I keep getting syntax errors when trying to update a Mysql database with Node.js.  I am attempting to update a form. I am not sure I have the right syntax.

All my other request works such as inserting into the form, retrieving data from the from, deleting from the form except the update request. I have tried two(2) options below but both will not work.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an alternative way to update a form?

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
        <OPTION 1>
         app.post('/edit',(req,res)=>{ 
         var sql = "UPDATE stores (ID, Station, Address, `Monthly C-Store 
         Sales`, Operator, `Top SKU`) \ VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"


         id = req.body.ID;
         station = req.body.Station;
         address = req.body.Address;
         monthlycstoresales = req.body.MonthlyCStoreSales;
         operator = req.body.Operator;
         topsku = req.body.TopSKU;


        db.query(sql, [id, station, address, monthlycstoresales, operator, 
                 topsku], (err, results, field) => {
        if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return;
        } else{
         res.send(results);
         };
         });
         });
    ``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
          <OPTION 2>
          app.post('/edit',(req,res)=>{ 
          var params = [req.body, req.query.id]

           db.query('UPDATE FROM stores WHERE id = ?', [params],(err, rows, 
                   fields)=>{
             if(!err)
            res.redirect('/alldata');
            //console.log('Update Successful');  
            else
            console.log(err);
            //return;

            });
            });


````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
CORRECTED UPDATED SYNTAX
       app.post('/edit',(req,res)=>{ 

       var sql ="UPDATE stores SET Station = ?, Address = ?, `Monthly C-Store 
       Sales` = ?, Operator = ?, `Top SKU` = ? WHERE id = ?"


       station = req.body.Station;
       address = req.body.Address;
       monthlycstoresales = req.body.MonthlyCStoreSales;
       operator = req.body.Operator;
       topsku = req.body.TopSKU;
       id = req.body.ID;


       db.query(sql, [station, address, monthlycstoresales, operator, topsku, 
       id], 
      (err, results, field) => {

        if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return;
        } else{
        res.send(results);
        };
        });
        });
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Can you share the exact error you're getting?

Comment: @Mureinik....It is saying I have a syntax error near "UPDATE stores (ID, Station, Address, `Monthly C-Store 
         Sales`, Operator, `Top SKU`) \ VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

Comment: Do you know of an alternative way to request an update....I am new to node.js..

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for your `update` statement is incorrect. It should be something like this (anad of course you need to bind the values in the corresponding order):

```
UPDATE stores
SET    `Station` = ?,
       `Address` = ?, 
       `Monthly C-Store Sales` = ?,
       `Operator` = ?,
       `Top SKU`=?
WHERE  id = ?
```

Comment: .....I have updated the syntax code above......should I have removed the id variable when binding?

Comment: @flowover - no, but you should move it to the end of the list - it should be bound to the placeholder in the `where` clause.

Comment: @Mureinik.......Hi....I used the code update query in postman and it worked. However, when updating in node from the frontend, it returns null values and it says that no rows have been affected.  Do you have any idea why this may be the case.  I am able to see all the values when I perform a req.body on the variables but the mysql table is not up updated.